# Why "vagrant up" gives me an error?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am installing the datasciencetoolbox and after entering the `valgrant up` I am receiving the following error:

```
dyn-72-33-239-166:psql mona$ mkdir MyDataScienceToolbox
dyn-72-33-239-166:psql mona$ cd MyDataScienceToolbox/
dyn-72-33-239-166:MyDataScienceToolbox mona$ vagrant init data-science-toolbox/dst
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
dyn-72-33-239-166:MyDataScienceToolbox mona$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The box 'data-science-toolbox/dst' could not be found.


dyn-72-33-239-166:MyDataScienceToolbox mona$ ls -la Vagrantfile 
-rw-r--r--  1 mona  staff  4646 Aug 25 20:55 Vagrantfile
```

[image]

I am following this tutorial: [DataScienceToolBox](http://datasciencetoolbox.org/)

Comment: Strange, that box does exist: https://vagrantcloud.com/data-science-toolbox/dst Can you paste the contents of the generated Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an old version of Vagrant, perhaps? Here's what those commands do for me:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'data-science-toolbox/dst' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'data-science-toolbox/dst'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/data-science-toolbox/dst
==> default: Adding box 'data-science-toolbox/dst' (v0.1.5) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/data-science-toolbox/dst/version/1/provider/virtualbox.box
==> default: Waiting for cleanup before exiting...
```

The fact that yours doesn't even attempt to retrieve the box from vagrantcloud suggests an old version, maybe.

You can get your version with `$ vagrant version`.

Answer (score 0):

This box needs version 1.5+ so I updated to version 1.6 downloading from this website and now it is working
http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html